# Getting django localization working with es-xl (Latin America Spanish)

Tags: django

iOS 8 has two language choices for Spanish. Español and Español (Mexico).

If I switch to **Español** and the browser sends `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: es-es` everything works perfectly.

When switching my iPad to **Español (Mexico)** localization defaults back to English. When looking at the headers I can see `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: es-xl`.

I have tried adding es_XL and ex_MX translation file in my locale directory with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your web site work properly if you browse it using a PC with espanol localization?

Comment: If I use Chrome on my MacBook and change the language to Spanish it works properly and translates the file.

Comment: That would indicate that the problem is related to the iPad. You could use Wireshark to capture the all the data that is streamed back and fourth and find out for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue ended up being that neither django or python supports the language code es-xl. The language code that iOS sends when setting the system language to Español (Mexico). So my solution was to create middleware that when es-xl is present I activate es-mx as the current language.

```
class LanguageCodeVerification(object):                            
    def process_request(self, request):                            
      #iOS sends unsupported language code es-xl                   
      if request.META.get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE','')[0:5] == 'es-xl':
          user_language = 'es-mx'                                     
          translation.activate(user_language)                      
          request.session['django_language'] = user_language
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, that worked perfectly for me is to add the missing language code es_XL, assuming it is called when your device is set to language: Español (Mexico).

In **/Zend/Locale.php** file add the locale date in:

```
$_localeData = array(
 'es_XL' => true, ...
```

Then, assign the territory in:

```
$_territoryData = array(
  'XL' => 'es_XL', ...
```

Finally, in **/Zend/Locale/Data/** you need to duplicate the file es_MX.xml and rename it as es_XL.xml

Problem gone!